# How can I get unbuffered input to a program?

Tags: raku

I can't figure out how to get unbuffered input.

I tried:

```
    method get-selection() {
        getc();
    }
```

Also tried Term::ReadKey module:

```
use Term::ReadKey;
    method get-selection() {
        read-key();
    }
```

But I still have to hit enter before I can capture the input. Couldn't find anything in the docs that might help.

I'm on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Handle#routine_getc states:

> Using getc to get a single keypress from a terminal will only work properly if you've set the terminal to "unbuffered".

For MacOS, a Google search gets me to:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193138/to-install-unbuffer-in-osx

Comment: Ok but what if it’s a computer I have no control over? I want the module to work the same way.

Comment: Hmmm... under investigation: https://irclogs.raku.org/moarvm/2022-06-17.html#12:02